# Where is my disk?

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning, disk-space

I installed Windows 10. I have 256Gb drive. When installing I choose to have 117Gb for Windows folders and all the System. And everything else I chose to be my main drive. Now I open My Computer try to go to main drive and just do not see it. So, my question is how can I make it visible?

Here is a screenshot that the disk is absent:

[image]

Here is what I tried:

`Once your in Disk Management and you can see your 2nd hard drive, you'll need to assign a letter to it. Right Click on the Drive > Change Drive Drive Letter and Paths > Choose a letter. Once this is done you'll be find your 2nd or 3rd HDD when you open My Computer. If you can't then you'll definitely need to format it.`

Here is what I see in Disk Management:

[image]

Does that mean that I should reinstall the windows or is it possible to tweak something so that to be able to make that second disk visible?

Comment: That "Create and format hard disk partitions" **is** Disk Management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> -> "Disk Management". You should see one disk with two partitions, one being your C-Drive. Right-Click on the other and assign a drive letter (if it already is a formatted partition) or format it and assign a drive letter in the process.

Comment: Its called Disk Management

Comment: Thank you for the help. I edited the question a little bit after getting prompt in the comment section. What should I do if there is no disk over there?

Comment: But I can see it in your screenshot (look in the lower half of the disk management window). In Windows, a disk is the physical drive, while partitions are...well, partitions. One disk can hold mutliple partitions - now, your disk just holds the system partition and some empty space (the black-labeled block). Just right-click on that block.

Comment: @flolilolilo, let us go in chat if you have such an opportunity, please. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61212/creating-main-disk-in-windows-10